# How do I take an image and make it an Brand Icon for my Nav Bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I would like to add an Brand Icon to my `Site Name` on my `nav bar`. I read in the Bootstrap nav bar components that I can do this with . How do I source this image if it is something that was created on my desktop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link your image to your navbar like this:

```
<a class="navbar-brand"><img src=" path-to-file/your image.jpg"/></a>
```

You will need to upload the image to a folder in your server and change the `path-to-file` above accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If the `Image` is in the desktop than simply left click on the image and get the properties of that image and then `copy` the location given in the properties of image and `paste` it in `src="Paste Here"`.

Hope it helps..